# Cannot connect to Oracle 12c from Tomcat 6: no matching authentication protocol (ORA-28040)

Tags: jakarta-ee, database-connection, tomcat6, oracle12c

I have to connecto to an Oracle 12c database from Tomcat 6. I made a servlet that create a connection to this datasource (from `META-INF/context.xml`):

```
<Context debug="0" docBase="/Test" path="/" reloadable="true">
   <Resource
      name="jdbc/test" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@somewhere:someport:someservice"
      username="someuser" password="somepass" maxActive="10" maxIdle="5"
      maxWait="5000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      logAbandoned="true"
   />
</Context>
```

When I create the connection using this code:

```
InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
Context ctx = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/test");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at tomcattest.TestIt.doPost(TestIt.java:48)
    at tomcattest.TestIt.doGet(TestIt.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOsesskey(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:294)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:357)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 18 more
```

But creating the connection with this code

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@somewhere:someport:someservice", "someuser", "somepass");
```

works fine; moreover, if I use an URL to an Oracle 11g database in the servlet, it works.

I am using `ojdbc6.jar` driver for Oracle 12c, Tomcat 6, Java 1.6, Windows 7. Anyone have some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved moving to Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have set the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION in the sql.net ora file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but with the parameter **SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER**

I set it to 8 to be sure.

See the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2016